# Output in windows form

Tags: c++, .net, forms

How do I duplicate cout<<process<<" took "<<time<<"seconds"<<endl in windows form in c++ where process is a character array and time is an integer?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::stringstream str;
str << blah << blah << blah;
whatever.setText(str.str());
```

It is not entirely clear from your question precisely what it is you are asking, but does this answer it?